# On Android, what is the correct way to open add new contact with a prefilled contact sheet?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contacts

I'd like to open the "save new contact" dialog with the sheet prefilled with street addess, phone number, email etc. Then the user can modify, add to or save.

I've seen a few methods.

1) this method is deprecated, but works for the most part (can't get to work with compound types like address).

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                        i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                        i.putExtra(Insert.NAME,"Name");
                        i.putExtra(Insert.PHONE,"Number");
                        startActivity(i);
```

2) This method seems like a good solution, but I can't attach this data to an intent to open the contacts app. It is only for programatically inserting the new contact automatically.

```
ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> op=new ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation>();
                    /*  ops.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, mSelectedAccount.getType()) 
                    .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, mSelectedAccount.getName()) 
            .build()); */
     op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, name)
             .build());
     op.add(ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
             .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
             .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER,phone).build());

            getContentResolver().applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, op);
```

What is the best practice to solve this issue?

thank you.

Comment: "this method is deprecated" -- really?

Comment: I get this warning from the IDE 

Multiple markers at this line
 - The field Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME is 
  deprecated
 - The type Contacts.Intents.Insert is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you are using the wrong constants. The Insert.NAME which you are using is from the class

```
Contacts.Intents.Insert
```

which was deprecated in API Level 5. It was replaced with the class

```
ContactsContract.Intents.Insert
```

If you use the constants from this class you should be fine! I have updated your code accordingly:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT_OR_EDIT);
                        i.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);
                        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.NAME,"Name");
                        i.putExtra(ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.PHONE,"Number");
                        startActivity(i);
```

You can find documentation for the ContactsContract.Intents.Insert class [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html) and some general information about modifying contacts using intents [here](http://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html)

Comment: Eclipse throws warnings telling me Insert.NAME is depricated

Multiple markers at this line
 - The field Contacts.Intents.Insert.NAME is 
  deprecated
 - The type Contacts.Intents.Insert is deprecated

Comment: Ah yes, my mistake, this class was replaced with ContactsContract. I will edit my answer. Here is the documentation of ContactsContract: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.html

Comment: @Joel: You are mixing and matching `ContactsContract` and `Contacts`. Remove all references to `Contacts`, changing them as appropriate to `ContactsContract`.